# Securely encrypt drive, able to be decrypted independently of the OS

Tags: cryptography, disk-encryption, file-encryption

I need a software to encrypt drives like USB pens, disc drives, ... to securely store the data. But most of the software I've found to encrypt and decrypt drives is OS dependent.

For example Windows BitLocker encrypted drives can't be decrypted on Linux or Android without additional software or tweaks.

What I need is a software that can encrypt a drive that could be decrypted by Windows, Linux or Android. In other words that is cross-platform compatible.

What encryption software do you recommend? Do you have any tool that you've been using and recommend?

Comment: Have you looked at [encrypted USB drives](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=encrypted+USB+drive&es_th=1). They perform encryption/decryption on the USB drive and not in the OS.

Comment: Truecrypt was the most cross-platform option.  I haven't used any of the forks to see if the compatibility is being maintained.

Comment: See [Alternatives to TrueCrypt?](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/4539/alternatives-to-truecrypt)

Comment: If you want a truly cross platform solution - look at getting a hardware solution.

Comment: Tool recommendations are off-topic. Did you want to rephrase?